# Express server configuration issues, the public directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I created two separate separate bundles, one for my server and one for my client. However the client bundle is still not getting downloaded by the browser when someone accesses the root route.

I told Express to treat the `public/` folder as a freely available public directory here inside of `index.js`:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const content = renderToString(<Home />);
```

I also added an HTML snippet with an ES6 template string like so:

```
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import Home from './client/components/Home';

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const content = renderToString(<Home />);

  const html = `<html><head><body><div>${content}</div><script src="bundle.js"></script></body></head></html>`;

  res.send(content);
});
```

The idea is when a user gets a response from this endpoint they will see the content from the `<Home />` component, but also tell the users browser to go back to my server and download the `bundle.js` file.

The expectation is that I refresh the page and instantly retrieve localhost and make a request for `bundle.js` file and see the console log I added in the `Home.js` component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>I am an OK home component</div>
      <button onClick={() => console.log('Howdy!')}>Press me!</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I refreshed the browser and did not see the console log nor a `bundle.js` file in Network tab.

What gives here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I created the variable `html` where I stored the HTML from the template string with the bundle.js file in it, but then I don't use that variable anywhere.

I had to replace `res.send(content);` with `res.send(html);`.